# EF inheritance with TPT - how to specify the foreign key column name?

Tags: entity-framework, single-table-inheritance

I want to map two derived classes to two tables (TPT)

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee : User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}
```

The tables already exist (i.e. I can't modify the schema) and are defined like this:

[image]

[image]

**Note that the column `UserId` in table `Employee` is both its PK and a FK to table `User`, column `Id`.**

The DbContext is as straight as possible - no fluent mappings defined.

```
public class TestInheritContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to access the `Users` collection, I get the following EF exception:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Id'.

Apparently, it tries to read column `Id` from the table `Employee`.

All examples of TPT that I have seen use the same PK column name in all the tables. For instance, [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt).

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `[Key("UserId")] ` on your `UserId` property ?

Comment: @jbl That property is already mapped to the column of the same name. The problem is, the `Id` property of the base class is inherited in class `Employee` and EF tries to read it from column `Id` in table `Employee`, which does not exist.

Comment: So I guess you didn't try ;-) I fluently map TPT hierarchy with different column names for parent and child key columns. The only needed point is specifying the Key and its column name in both types.

Comment: I *did* try that. Same error. Btw, the `[Key]` attribute ctor doesn't take any parameters. I used both `[Key]` and `[Column("UserId")]`.

Comment: @jbl PS. Yup, fluent mapping is what I have arrived at too - any opinions on my answer below?

Comment: Seems fine. From my experience trying to access objects in a DbSet<Employee> crashes. I always have to use DbSet<User>.OfType<Employee>... Let me know if this works for you

Comment: @jbl I already checked. I was curious if `.OfType()` gets run on the DB or locally. Happy to report that `DbSet<Employee>` and `DbSet<User>.OfType<Employee>` both work *and* the generated SQL is identical. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.

First, in order to debug this, it was helpful to see the actual mapping that EF creates behind the scenes.

I installed the [`EF Power Tools`](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) VS extension, r-clicked the context file,

`Entity Framework -> View Entity Data Model`

and got this:

[image]

Notice the entity `Employee` has both its own `UserId` property *and* the inherited `Id` property.

So the first thing I did was remove the `UserId` property from the derived class:

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee : User
{
    // not needed
    //public int UserId { get; set; } 

    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}
```

This isn't enough, though. I now have the `Id` property from the base class that has to point to two differentlynamed columns, depending on which table/entity it's coming from:

For `User`: Id => Id
For `Employee`: Id => UserId

There's no way I can use attributes for that, so I'll go with fluent syntax.

For the `User` entity, I don't *have* to do anything, since the column name matches the property name.

For the `Employee` entity I have to intervene:

```
public class TestInheritContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("UserId");
    }
}
```

This finally produces the correct mapping: [image]